# Hide rows that contain a specific value in a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need to hide rows that have value "ST" in cells of a fixed column (column A)
This function hide rows that contain balck cells in column 53. How can I get not blanks cells but cells with "ST" value?

```
function nascondiRighe() {

// This hides rows with blank cells    
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("VT.Attivita"); 
var lastRow=sheet.getMaxRows();
var lastColumn=sheet.getMaxColumns();
var range=sheet.getRange(1, 53, lastRow, 1);
var data=range.getValues();
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
  if(!data[i][0])
  {
   sheet.hideRow(range);
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the if loop.

```
function nascondiRighe() {
    // This hides rows with blank cells    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("VT.Attivita");
    var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 53, lastRow, 1);
    var data = range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] == "ST") {
            sheet.hideRows(i + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be more better for compiling time because Lastrow/LastColumn is better then max rows/columns,you just need to loop for cells with values not all whatever cells

```
  function nascondiRighe() {

// This hides rows with 'ST' cells    
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("VT.Attivita"); 
var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
var arr=sheet.getRange(1,53,lastRow,1).getValues();

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
  if(arr[i][0]==='ST')
  {
   sheet.hideRows(i+1);
  }
}
}
```